# Configure phpunit.xml

Tags: php, phpunit

My phpunit.xml -

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     stopOnError="false"
     stopOnIncomplete="false"
     stopOnSkipped="false"
     stopOnRisky="false">
```

But it stopped whatever, after first error. I am sure that I use right file.

Comment: How are you running the unit test (command line, through an IDE)?

Comment: from docker container. Command line "php artisan test"